# Teamcity Build Chain Optional Builds

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, pipeline, build-automation, build-chain

I have a TeamCity project which includes 4 configurations in the build chain like this.

```
         |----> Build A -|
Prebuild-|               |----> Test Results
         |----> Build B -|
```

In the Prebuild configuration based on tags in the Pull Requests I set a variable build which can be "A" or "B" or "A,B". Based on this I need to start just A or just B or both.

Do you know if this is possible?